# Can't display foreign key related object in Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, class, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've got a booking class which is related to Customer and Barber models. I can display all bookings using the detail view, however, can't figure out how to display a booking/bookings that a specific barber has. Basically, I want to get a booking or multiple bookings of a barber based on the ID given to the url.

Here is my model:

```
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    barber_id = models.ForeignKey(Barber, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    timeslot = models.DateTimeField('appointment')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customer_id} {self.barber_id} {self.timeslot}"
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("model_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

My view:

```
class GetBarberBooking(DetailView):
   model = Booking
   template_name = "barber_booking.html"

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['barber'] = Booking.objects.filter(
           id=self.kwargs.get('<str:pk'))
       return context
```

My url path:

`path('barber-booking/<str:pk>/', views.GetBarberBooking.as_view(), name='barber-booking'),`

Comment: Can you filter like this see if this works: `Booking.objects.filter(barber_id__id=id=self.kwargs.get('<str:pk'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove this piece of code:

```
context['barber'] = Booking.objects.filter(
           id=self.kwargs.get('<str:pk'))
```

And in template just use:

```
{{ object.barber_id }}
```

And show all the booking for barber:

```
{{ object.barber_id.booking_set.all }}
```

It will show all the the barber. This works because of FK relation between Booking and Barber model. More information can be found in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). For reverse relation (Many to one), please check [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

FYI, you do not need to create a field name suffix with `_id`, because Django creates that automatically for you.

**Also, if you want to query a Barber, then you should use Barber as the model in the DetailView. Then you can use a similar query mentioned above:**

```
# view
class GetBarberBooking(DetailView):
   model = Barber

# template
{{ object.booking_set.all }}
```

Comment: I'm getting <queryset> when using that line in the template. I assume this has something do with serializers? I used them in functional views but not sure how to use with CBV.

Comment: you can loop through the queryset like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-loop-django-template-tags/amp/